# Bootstrap template modification

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am using a bootstrap template which I downloaded from a website.Now my project manager said that I should design according to following image.Now how can I reduce body width and how can I align images according to following image.What CSS file should I change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change the bootstrap css

you just have to use their grid system to left align

[bootstrap doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: can you please explain,babasLH

Comment: on the template you used you have on offset of 2 or 3 on the left, just remove it and your body will be left adjust, then bootstrap use a grid system of 12 columns wide, col-md-n with n from 1 to 12